# ProgressBar in IJulia printing every new line

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I am currently learning Julia and have been practicing in the Jupyter notebook environment. However, the ProgressBar package (similar to TQDM in python) is updated every new line instead of updating on the same line (picture attached). Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

**UPDATE** : Here is the full function that I wrote.

```
function spike_rate(raw_dat, width)

    N = size(raw_dat)[1]
    domain = collect(1:N);
    spike_rat = zeros(N);

    for i in ProgressBar(1:N)
        dx = i .- domain;
        window = gaussian.(dx, width);
        spike_rat[i] = sum(window .* raw_dat) ./ width;
    end

    return spike_rat;

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known](https://github.com/cloud-oak/ProgressBars.jl/issues/49) [issue](https://github.com/cloud-oak/ProgressBars.jl/issues/44) with ProgressBars.jl, unfortunately. It's not clear what changed to make these progress bars not work properly anymore, but [the maintainer's comment](https://github.com/cloud-oak/ProgressBars.jl/issues/49#issuecomment-954716992) says that tqdm uses "a custom ipywidget" to make this work for the Python library, and that hasn't been implemented for the Julia package yet.

To expand on @Zitzero's mention of `] up`, that calls `Pkg.update()` which also prints a progress bar - so the suggestion is to use the mechanism `Pkg` uses for it. `Pkg` has an internal module called `MiniProgressBars` which handles this output.

---

**Edit**: Tim Holy's [ProgressMeter](https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl) package seems well-maintained, and is a much better option than relying on an internal non-exported `Pkg` submodule with no docs. So I'd recommend ProgressMeter over the below.

The Readme mentions a [caveat](https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl#progressmeter-with-additional-information-in-jupyter) regarding printing additional information with the progress bar when in Jupyter, which likely  applies to `MiniProgressBar` as well. So, using `ProgressMeter`, and separating the progress output vs other relevant output to different cells, seems like the best option.

---

*(not recommended)*

```
using Pkg.MiniProgressBars

bar = MiniProgressBar(; indent=2, header = "Progress", color = Base.info_color(),
                              percentage=false, always_reprint=true)
bar.max = 100

# start_progress(stdout, bar)
for i in 1:100
    sleep(0.05) # replace this with your code
    # print_progress_bottom(stdout)
    bar.current = i 
    show_progress(stdout, bar)
end
# end_progress(stdout, bar)
```

This is based on how `Pkg` uses it, [from this file](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Pkg.jl/blob/master/src/Operations.jl#L988). The commented out lines (with `start_progress`, `print_progress_bottom`, and `end_progress`) are in the original usage in `Pkg`, but it's not clear what they do and here they just seem to mess up the output - maybe I'm using them wrongly, or maybe Jupyter notebooks only support a subset of the ANSI codes that `MiniProgressBars` uses.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, the package module does that as far as I know when you do:

```
] up
```

Could you share a little of your code?
For example, where you define what is written to the console.
One guess is that

```
print("text and progressbar")
```

instead of

```
println("text and progressbar")
```

could help, because `println()` always creates a new line, while `print()` should just overwrite you current line.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code. I am not using the println() function for the progress bar. I  don't understand what Pkg.('up') does though, I will try it out and let you know if it works. Thanks a lot!